# xslt reuse key multiple times

Tags: xml, xslt

Context: starting to learn xslt, and having an issue on grouping/keys

so, I have this input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="getInfoMinimal.xml" type="text/xsl" ?>
<domaines>
    <domaine Name="someDomain">
        <application name="someApplication1">
            <module id="0001">
                <env-entry>ejb/test</env-entry>
                <requirement>Queue1</requirement>
            </module>
            <module id="0002">
                <env-entry>ejb/notherTest</env-entry>
                <requirement>Queue1</requirement>
            </module>
            <module id="0003">
                <env-entry>ejb/notherTest2</env-entry>
                <requirement>Datasource1</requirement>
            </module>
            <module id="0004">
                <env-entry>ejb/notherTest3</env-entry>
                <requirement>Datasource1</requirement>
            </module>
        </application>
        <application name="someApplication2">
            <module id="0001">
                <env-entry>ejb/test</env-entry>
                <requirement>Queue1</requirement>
            </module>
            <module id="0002">
                <env-entry>ejb/notherTest</env-entry>
                <requirement>Queue1</requirement>
            </module>
            <module id="0003">
                <env-entry>ejb/notherTest2</env-entry>
                <requirement>Datasource1</requirement>
            </module>
            <module id="0004">
                <env-entry>ejb/notherTest3</env-entry>
                <requirement>Datasource1</requirement>
            </module>
            <module id="0001">
                <env-entry>ejb/test</env-entry>
                <requirement>Queue1</requirement>
            </module>
            <module id="0002">
                <env-entry>ejb/notherTest</env-entry>
                <requirement>Queue1</requirement>
            </module>
            <module id="0003">
                <env-entry>ejb/notherTest2</env-entry>
                <requirement>Datasource1</requirement>
            </module>
            <module id="0004">
                <env-entry>ejb/notherTest3</env-entry>
                <requirement>Datasource3</requirement>
            </module>
        </application>
    </domaine>
</domaines>
```

and this xlst file(getInfoMinimal.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:key name="modules-by-requirement" match="module" use="requirement" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="/domaines/domaine/@Name"/></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="/domaines/domaine/application">
                    <h1><xsl:value-of select="./@name"/></h1>
                    <xsl:for-each select="module[count(. | key('modules-by-requirement', requirement)[1]) = 1]">
                        <!--<xsl:sort select="requirement" />-->
                        <xsl:value-of select="requirement" /><br />
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('modules-by-requirement', requirement)">
                        <!--<xsl:sort select="env-entry" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="env-entry" /> (<xsl:value-of select="blabla" />)<br />-->
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm trying to render it to a html page that lists per application all the requirements that its modules have.

rules implied by the input XML:

- 1 application can have 1 or more modules
- 1 module can have 1 or more unique requirements
- multiple modules can have the same requirements
- multiple applications can not have the same modules
- multiple applications can have the same requirements.

**Current result:**

someApplication1

- Queue1
- Datasource1

someApplication2

- Datasource3

**wanted result:**

someApplication1

- Queue1
- Datasource1

someApplication2

- Queue1
- Datasource1
- Datasource3

as you can see, the Queue1 and Datasource1 are not in the 'someApplication2' result, even though I want them to be.

Any and all help will be appreciated

Comment: Before getting into this: your stylesheet declares version 2.0. Why are you using the *Muenchian grouping* method, when XSLT 2.0 has built-in grouping: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping ?

Comment: my stylesheet declares de 2.0 because I've tried the grouping from 2, but couldn't get it to work either(nor do I have a code sample anymore)

Comment: Are you in fact using an XSLT 2.0 processor? -- Perhaps a more pertinent question: do you want to learn XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Judging from the PI at the top, OP may likely be using a browser.

Comment: OP is in fact using a browser. I'm not averse to using a processor, however, it would mean an additional scheduled task that is possibly overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want distinct keys for each application/requirement combination, you can use a concatenation of the application name and requirement name as your key value:

```
<xsl:key name="modules-by-requirement" match="module" 
         use="concat(../@name, '+', requirement)" />
```

Then the full solution looks like this (cleaned up a bit to use templates and the more efficient Muenchian grouping style):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="modules-by-requirement" match="module" 
           use="concat(../@name, '+', requirement)" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="/domaines/domaine/@Name"/>
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/domaines/domaine/application" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="application">
    <xsl:variable name="appName" select="@name"/>
    <h1>
      <xsl:value-of select="$appName"/>
    </h1>
    <xsl:variable name="distinctModules"
                  select="module[generate-id() = 
                                 generate-id(key('modules-by-requirement', 
                                                 concat($appName, '+', requirement))[1])
                                ]" />
    <xsl:if test="$distinctModules">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$distinctModules" />
    </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="module">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="requirement" />
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>someDomain</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>someApplication1</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Queue1</li>
      <li>Datasource1</li>
    </ul>
    <h1>someApplication2</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Queue1</li>
      <li>Datasource1</li>
      <li>Datasource3</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```